# how to upload with IvoryCkEditorBundle

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Currently, I'm working with the IvoryCkEditorBundle, I read the doc but I didn't understand how can I  upload pictures when I submit the Ckeditor area. I saw you can add specifics options like : "filebrowserBrowseRoute" but I don't understand how it work.

See the doc here: [the doc](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)

Comment: Can you point to where specifically it is? I really don't feel like reading all of the docs to understand what you are not getting. I'm sure others wouldn't want to either. Specific question would help.

Comment: Ok, so for use it, you must first install the bundle, and after you just setup in a formType: Like `code`->add('nameOfField', 'ckeditor', array(option...))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an filebrowser, thirdparty, or written by yourself.
As a example you can use Elfinder, configured by yourself or via bundle, like [FMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle) 
The readme explains how to configure bundle to work with [trsteel CKeditor bundle](https://github.com/trsteel88/TrsteelCkeditorBundle), but configuration for Ivory should be almost the same