# How to browse a directory within trsteel CKEditor ?

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor

I have successfully installed trsteel CKEditor for symfony 2, and it works fine except for image upload.

When I try to browse the server to updload an image, it returns me the html page and not the directory (the route is configure to show a webpage but I don't know how to do overwise).

Comment: You should post your routes and your `access_control` in your `security.yml` file

Comment: should i put this inside the security.yml ?:  route_name:
                    url:  /images/

Comment: If you followed all the steps correctly, this should work. If it doesn't, it could means that some kind of previous config prevent it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered almost the same question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520855/how-to-upload-with-ivoryckeditorbundle/17528870#17528870)
Shortly, you need a bundle to work with files on the server side, and provide integration with ckeditor.